# How to display the datatype of a variable in pl-sql

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

I have a field "DIVISIONS" which has pipe (|) separated NUMBERs. I split the pipe separated values using following cursor in DECLARE section as below. I join it with a table because I need to obtain some other field from the table based on each value I split and add those values. The field in table is NUMBER(38).

```
FUNCTION foo (divisions IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
      CURSOR splitDiv
      IS
        SELECT ud.* FROM (
          SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(divisions, '[^|]+', 1, ROWNUM) AS division
          FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(divisions, '[^|]+'))  + 1
          ) d
        JOIN ud
        ON NVL(TO_NUMBER(d.division),0) = NVL(TO_NUMBER(ud.udValue),0);

  divStatusVar NUMBER(38) := 0;

BEGIN

  FOR d IN splitDiv
  LOOP
    divStatusVar := divStatusVar + TO_NUMBER(d.status);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN divStatusVar ;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Code : ' || SQLCODE || ' Error : ' || SQLERRM);
    RETURN divStatusVar ;
END foo;
```

This is how I call the function:

```
DECLARE
...
status NUMBER(38) := 0;
...
BEGIN
...
status := foo('1234|6789');
...
END;
```

When I execute the code above, I get following error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-01403: no data found
```

I am clueless as to why this error is thrown. I want to see the datatype of "d.status". I have access to the database and the table UD, and the datatype of this field is NUMBER(38), but I am not sure if it's still the same after obtaining the rows in Cursor.

Is there any way I can print the datatype of this field/variable?
Or is there anything else that I am missing here?
Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: Which line throws the error? If you try passing a single number, like `1234`, to your `foo` function, is the error occurring? If you try running the query from the cursor as a standalone query, does it work?

Comment: I guess the FOR loop throws the error, If I comment it it doesn't throw any error. Yes, I tried with just single number like '1234' to the function, and it works fine. Also, when I run the cursor query from Toad as follows, and it works fine too.

`with t as (select '1234|6789' divisions from dual)
SELECT ud.* FROM (
          SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(divisions, '[^|]+', 1, ROWNUM) AS division
          FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(divisions, '[^|]+'))  + 1
          ) d
JOIN ud
ON NVL(TO_NUMBER(d.division),0) = NVL(TO_NUMBER(ud.udValue),0);`

Comment: The code above is not formatted, so pasting it here again. Hope it formats properly this time.  

`with t as (select '1234|6789' divisions from dual)    
SELECT ud.* FROM (    
          SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(divisions, '[^|]+', 1, ROWNUM) AS division FROM DUAL  
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(divisions, '[^|]+'))  + 1 ) d    
JOIN ud ON NVL(TO_NUMBER(d.division),0) = NVL(TO_NUMBER(ud.udValue),0);`

Comment: Just FYI - when I run this it works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing (pipe) separated values in the first place. Why not fix your data model instead?

Comment: @BobJarvis Did you try the query I posted in comment? That works for me too. My PL-SQL block doesn't run. I doubt if the REGEXP functions work the same way in PL-SQL block.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Unfortunately, this is the data I receive from my client in a csv file (along with some more fields). I load that data in a table and then process it. I have no control over how client stores data at their end.

Comment: You should have mentioned in your question that you are loading a CSV file and that you are trying to fix the data in that file.

Comment: I agree that I should have mentioned about csv file. But I was under the impression that the issue was in the code instead of in the data file, since I was using the DB table to parse the values in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for providing inputs!
Here is what happened -

As mentioned in one of the comments on the question, I am loading a csv format input file into the staging table. And then one of the columns in staging table was passed as a parameter to the function FOO. 
While loading the data I had used following property of SQL Loader.

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

But in the sample file I was using the values were simply separated by comma WITHOUT double quotes (""). I changed the file to have each value in the file enclosed by doubt quotes, loaded this file in staging table and then executed the above procedure, it's working perfectly fine. So the problem lies not in the code but in the file.

Thanks everyone for taking time to go through my question, and for providing inputs!